# What could slow the download speed of Steam and Origin?

Tags: networking, windows-10, download

For like 2 years now I'm having an issue with my download speed on Steam or Origin : It is locked at 2MBs.
I switch ISP during those two years but no luck with that.
Right now I have a fiber 1Gbs/1Gbs internet connection and when I download with P2P, a browser or on my PS4 I have no problem.
But when I try to download on Steam or Origin  I get stuck to around 2MBs (1.9-2.1).
I contacted the support of both platforms but they were not able to help me, so the question is : What could on my pc limit my download speed for Steam/Origin ?

Windows 10 pro 64b
1GBs Ethernet cable cat6

EDIT :

I tried all regions on steam and set the "no limit" limit.
What happens is this : The speed starts at 50mb and the goes to 2mbs in 5 to 20 seconds.
I have an SSD.

Comment: Does this happen for downloads of all sizes? Does the speed decrease for you when you download a large file in your browser? If so, my guess would be that your hard drive might not be keeping up.

Comment: I have an SSD so that's not the problem.
When I download from my browser I don't have any issue even with the big files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QOS/Proritizing packets was automatically enabled on all my network cards.
my netgear switches have it enabled by default too.
This means that all download etc were limited by it and now that everything is disabled I get 1gbs and I download a 30gb game in less than 5min.

Answer (score 0):

Remove bandwidth limit to **No limit**

Also select **Download region** that's best for you

[image]

Comment: Already tried them all (not kidding)

Comment: And I already have "no limit" set

Comment: It is your Download Region Server + ISP; Steam servers get flooded sometimes and thus you get slower speeds.

Comment: It always starts at 50mbs and in 20sec it goes down to 2

Comment: Those would have been helpful things to put in the original post, @rXp

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I updated the post.